# Accessing username in angular

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8, angular9

I am fairly new to frontend development. One question I was asked in angular interview and I was not able to answer it. Question is as follows:

Suppose you have a login screen and you enter username and password to login. Now after 5-6 pages or after n number of pages, there is a requirement that need username. How you will access username there?
My answer was I can use queryparam for it. Then interviewer told it can be done by queryparams but that is not a good way to always carry username in queryparams.

What should be the correct answer for this? How it can be done

Comment: Store it in local storage, session storage, or retrieve it from the server.

Comment: As @RobbyCornelissen said you cut put it in localStorage or sessionStorage but most of the times you would store this kind of information in a dedicated (auth) service when you retrieve it from a server

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have made a HTTP Request to GET the required information beforehand, you can save it to Local storage, Session Storage, or depending on the size of your web app, I often end up storing it in NgRx Store.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: use HTTP GET request to connected backend and retrieve the logged in user from there,which is stored while login is successful.

Method 2: In Angular we can store the logged in user in a *service*. And use dependency injection to get the variable value.(this might be the answer they expected if look from angular frontend perspective)
If you are in any page you can get value from angular service
The link below shows how it is implemented

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

Use tokens to get data from Back End when you log in. Make a class in your front end that have methods in it responsible for retrieving specific information from your token e.g. userName , Id , email etc.

You can call methods of this class wherever you need in your front end by just injecting that class(Containing METHODS responsible for retrieving info from token)

I prefer [JWT](https://jwt.io/)